# How do I access tables in Azure after authentication?

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication

I have been following the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library) but I am getting **stuck** after the **authentication** part. After I login I get the user id and token back but I don't know what to do after that. If I try to access the tables after logging in then it comes back with this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load sitename.azurewebsites.net/tables/modules.
>   Redirect from 'sitename.azurewebsites.net/tables/modules' to
>   'sitename.azurewebsites.net/tables/modules' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow
>   cross-origin redirect.

This is the code. It will give me back my userid and then come back with the error above when trying to access tables.

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://sitename.azurewebsites.net');
client.login("facebook").done(function (results) {
    console.log("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
    var table = client.getTable("modules");
    table.read().then(success, failure);
}, function (err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
});
```

Should it automatically work after I login or do I have to do some extra stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#footer) you provided,

> You also need to add the same loopback URLs to the CORS whitelist
> settings:
>
> 1. Navigate back to the Azure portal.
> 2. Navigate to your Mobile App backend.
> 3. Click **CORS** in the **API** menu.
> 4. Enter each URL in the empty **Allowed Origins** text box. A new text box is created.
> 5. Click **SAVE**
>
> After the backend updates, you will be able to use the new loopback URLs in your app.

Eventually, you will see something like this:

[image]

**Note:** You should also use `https://sitename.azurewebsites.net` instead of `http://sitename.azurewebsites.net` to request your App Service.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the asterisk and it still won't work. The login will still work though, I just can't access the tables still. I have added the code to the original post if you need to have a look at it. The tables are still using SQLite, should I create an SQL Azure data connection?

Comment: Yes, you should create a SQL Database and then configure `Data connections` in the Azure portal.

Comment: So I set up the database and the data connection and it's still not working. I'm new to all of this and I don't understand it.

Comment: I'm getting one error that is the same as the one in my original post and there is a new one that says: 

Uncaught Error: Error: Error loading data: (…)(anonymous function) @ azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0-beta5.js:12732

Comment: Are you using `Easy tables` on Mobile App?

Comment: It's Easy Tables on Mobile Apps Quickstart

Comment: Hi @Laserchalk, I have updated my reply. You should use `https://sitename.azurewebsites.net` instead of `http://sitename.azurewebsites.net` to request your App Service.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow for [Cross Origin Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN).